# print most k frequent numbers of list with rank ties

Tags: python, recursion

I was trying to find a way to print k most frequent number of the text file. I was able to sort those numbers into a list of lists with its number of appearance in the text file.

`l =[(0, 7), (3, 4), (-101, 3), (2, 3), (-3, 1), (-2, 1), (-1, 1), (101, 1)] # 0 is the number itself, 7 means it appeared in file 7 times, and etc`

So, now I want to print out k most frequent numbers of the file(should be done RECURSIVELY), but I am struggling with rank ties. For example, if k=3 I want to print:

`[(0, 7), (3, 4), (-101, 3), (2, 3)] # top 3 frequencies`

I tried doing:

```
def head(l): return l[0]

def tail(l): return l[1:]

def topk(l,k,e):
    if(len(l)<=1 or k==0):
        return [head(l)[1]]
    elif(head(l)[1]!=e):
        return [head(l)[1]] + topk(tail(l),k-1,head(l)[1])
    else:
        return [head(l)[1]] + topk(tail(l),k,head(l)[1])

l1 = [(0, 7), (3, 4), (-101, 3), (2, 3), (-3, 1), (-2, 1), (-1, 1), (101, 1)]
l2 = [(3.3, 4), (-3.3, 3), (-2.2, 2), (1.1, 1)]
print(topk(l1,3,''))
print(took(l2,3,''))
```

l1 prints correctly, but l2 has an extra frequency for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `sorted` built-in function with parameter `key` to get the last frequency from top `k` and then you can use a list comprehenstion to get all the elements that have the frequency `>=` than that min value:

```
v = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[1])[-3][1]
[e for e in l if e[1] >= v]
```

output:

```
[(0, 7), (3, 4), (-101, 3), (2, 3)]
```

---

if you want a recursive version you can use:

```
def my_f(l, v, top=None, i=0):

    if top is None:
        top = []

    if l[i][1] >= v:
        top.append(l[i])

    if i == len(l) - 1:
        return top

    return my_f(l, v, top, i+1)

def topk(l, k):
    k = min(len(l), k)
    v = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[1])[-3][1]
    return my_f(l, v)

topk(l, 3)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210885/discussion-on-answer-by-kederrac-print-most-k-frequent-numbers-of-list-with-rank).